# How to count common field in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
Id    Name     City
1     Hits     Baroda
2     Ajay     Chennai
3     Hitesh   Baroda
```

How to count the City and how to store it's counted value in a variable?

Comment: what do you want a select query or code in C#?

Comment: What problems have you encountered? What have you tried so far? Have you tried a simple search on Google first?

Answer (score 3):

**If you want just total count in city for try the query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCityCount From TableName
```

**If you want just the total count in city, removing duplicate cities**

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct City) as TotalCityCount  From   Your TableName
```

**And try this c# code for:**

```
public DataView GetCityCount()
{
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Put Your Connection String"))// **must Put Your Connection String**
   {
      string sql1 = string.Format(@"SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCityCount From TableName");
      SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);
      DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
      con.Open();
      da1.Fill(ds1);
      return ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   }
} 

Public Void getTotal()
{
   DataView dv=GetCityCount();
   int totalcity=Convert.ToInt32(dv.Tables[0]["TotalCityCount"])//You get the total Count value in this totalcity variable
}
```

Comment: a wrong answer, as OP wants count and city. and answer lacks explanation.

Comment: What you mean ?? please see  tat he question.

How to count the City and how to store it's counted value in a variable

he want total city count.and store a counted value only.not a city name ..

Comment: now it's good , whenever you post answer try to explain a lot. if you give a link, then later some time that site is down, so resource cannot be found. if you explained and posted answer here it would be great. i am upvoting for your effort to improving the answer

Answer (score 2):

This will give you count of person in each city and here you can get city count

```
SELECT 
      City, 
      COUNT(Id) as total 
 From 
      TableName 
 Group by 
       City
```

Result would be

```
Baroda    2
Chennai   1
```

OR if you just want the total city count then write it like this

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(distinct City) as total 
From 
     TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like these what you need

```
declare @Count int  --(or bigint)
Select @Count=count(city)
from Citytable
return @Count (or print @Count or Select @Count)
```